# Ajax Serialize Post not working with Django, Django doesn't see data

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a three part question:

Part 1: I'm trying to use Ajax to serialize data to Django and return values in real time, right now my ajax is just on form submit, but the part3 question will be in regards to that. Right now django doesn't receive the post data and the console message I have to see if its success or failure aren't displaying in the console. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#get_info');
    frm.submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                //$("#SOME-DIV").html(data);
                console.log('done');
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('something went wrong');
                //$("#MESSAGE-DIV").html("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

The browser bar changes to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/vmstatus/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=HApMk9LWlxNUdlJaD4kj0WZkCTki4hin&selected_customer=35&vm_status=Get+VMs+Status&user=True
```

part 2: is this safe to have the middlewaretoken displayed like that and the customer_id?

part 3: how do I set this ajax function up on a time to post every 1 minute?

obviously the serialize is getting the correct data, or it wouldn't be displayed in the url post bar correct? So what am I doing wrong why is django not getting the post or acting on it?

views.py

```
   if request.method == 'POST':   
      posted_data = request.POST.copy()
      customer_id = int(posted_data['selected_customer'])
      for customer in customers:
         if customer.customer_id == customer_id:
            selected_customer = ((decrypt('secretkey', customer.customer_name), int(customer.customer_id)))       
         customer_list.append((decrypt('secretkey', customer.customer_name), int(customer.customer_id)))
```

Made some modifications based on a comment. The form is successfully serializing the data now but still no django returned.

Here is the working code where the console outputs done as it was successful and the url doesnt change anymore, so I know its doing a post. However, Django still doesn't return info.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#get_info').submit(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            type: $('#get_info').attr('POST'),
            url: $('#get_info').attr('action'),
            data: $('#get_info').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('done');
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('something went wrong');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

I just saw a youtube video of a guy doing it like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#get_info').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/vmstatus/",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                data: {
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
                    selected_customer: $('selected_customer').val()
                },
                success: function (json) {
                    console.log('done');
                    setInterval(returnData, 5000);  
                    console.log(json);
                },
                error: function(json) {
                    console.log('something went wrong');
                    console.log(json);
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
});

var returnData = function () {
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/vmstatus/",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                data: {
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
                    selected_customer: $('selected_customer').val()
                },
                success: function (json) {
                    console.log('done');
                    console.log(json);
                },
                error: function(json) {
                    console.log('something went wrong');
                    console.log(json);
                }
            });
};  


</script>
```

for some reason though it says something went wrong. I'm not sure what im doing wrong with the ajax.

here is my form

```
<form id='get_info' name='queryForm'>
{% csrf_token %}


<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<center> 

     <div class=".col-xs-6 .col-md-4" >
      <table cellpadding='10' id='table-data' class="table table-striped" >
        <tbody>
            <td align='left' style='font-weight: bold;' {%if date_values %}width='20%'{%else%}width='50%'{%endif%}>Customer Select</td></tr>
      <td width='200' align='left'>
                Customer: <select name='selected_customer' style='width:200px;' id='selected_customer'>
                        {% if user.is_superuser == True %}
                            {% if selected_customer %}
                                <option name='selected_customer' value="{{selected_customer.1}}" selected>{{selected_customer.0}}</option>
                                {%else%}
                                <option name='selected_customer' value='0' selected>Select Customer:</option>
                            {%endif%}

                            {%for customer in customer_list%}
                                <option name='selected_customer' value="{{customer.1}}">{{customer.0}}</option>
                            {%endfor%}
                        {%else%}
                                {%for customer in customer_list%}
                                    <option name='selected_customer' value="{{customer.1}}">{{customer.0}}</option>
                                {%endfor%}
                        {% endif %}
                        </select><br><br>
                        <input type='submit' name='vm_status' value='Get VMs Status' style='width:270px;' class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Retrieve the status of your VMs">
</td>


    </table>        
    </center>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

updated views

```
posted_data = request.POST.get("selected_customer", "")
```

video i watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYNDXrLu57k

Comment: If the browser bar is changing, then a) your request is a GET not a POST, and b) your request is not being made via Ajax; so most likely your JS script is not running at all. You should probably post your template: what is `#get_info`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman hey thanks man it is my form id='get_info' I fixed my code realized I was being an idiot with the ajax. However, Django still doesn't return anything.

Comment: about your 3rd question: use setInterval

Comment: @DanielRoseman What am i doing wrong now with my ajax because it jsut outputs something went wrong.